# Control Panel shortcuts in ExpressionEngine 3

Tags: control-panel, navigation, ee3

In EE2, I could click the (+) icon in the top menu to add a shortcut button to the current page. These could be managed in my "Main Menu Manager" in my profile. This was really handy, but I cannot find a similar feature in EE3. Does such a feature exist out of the box, or are there any add-ons available to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems they moved this feature to be in a drop down menu rather than directly in the main UI.  I loved adding links to the top of the old EE, made things quick.  But now they are in the top right corner under your username dropdown.  When you click on your username you'll see a "new link" option, along with any other links you've already added.

You can also manage your links under "My profile->quick links".  With "my profile also under the username drop down in the top right.

Hope that helps.

Comment: AHA! Thanks, Chris. I should've been able to find that. Kinda stinks that you can't add links to the visible menus, and that these handy shortcuts are hidden in a dropdown.

Comment: I totally agree, makes them less "quick" if you have to hunt them down in a menu. You could probably jump over to the EE forums and throw that in a feature request.

Comment: I believe dorothy Dorothy's answer below (using the Menu Manger) is also worth looking at - it allows you to add a row of buttons across the top of the CP and assign them to user groups, which is extremely helpful. No add-on needed!

Answer (score 3):

You can add short cuts into the control panel using the Menu Manager.

1. Go to Settings (button in top right hand corner)
2. Choose "Menu Manager" from the left hand navigation (under General Settings)
3. Click on "Add Menu Item"
4. Choose "Single Link"
5. Give the link a name
6. Enter the relative path to the addon e.g. cp/addons/settings/freeform
7. Save
8. Save Menu Set

I'm not sure how to use the addon dropdown option.  Let me know if you work it out.  I hope that this helps.

[image: Edit Menu Item screen grab]

And here are the docs from EllisLab
https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/cp/settings/menu/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you may want to look at is Addon Menu. It helps a little. Still similar to clicking your name if you just want Addon Links, but it essentially does it for you.   ;)

https://github.com/amphibian/addon_menu.ee_addon